# Time taken for operation MongoDB

Tags: mysql, mongodb, explain, database, nosql

When performing an operation using MySQL, the following output is displayed:

```
Query OK, 996 rows affected (0.03 sec)
```

This was from deleting 996 records. Is there a way of attaining similar information when performing operations using MongoDB? I am particularly interested in the time taken.

Something similar to the `.explain()` flag but for removing or deleting records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `setVerboseShell(true)` in the `mongo` shell:

```
> setVerboseShell(true)

> db.testing.update({}, {$set: { deleteme: true }}, { multi:true })
Updated 100 existing record(s) in 1ms
WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 100, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 100 })

> db.testing.remove({ deleteme:true })
Removed 100 record(s) in 1ms
WriteResult({ "nRemoved" : 100 })
```

If you want this to be your default, you can add `setVerboseShell(true)` to your `~/.mongorc.js` file (which will be loaded when the `mongo` shell starts).

Comment: Note: the `setVerbosShell()` shell command doesn't appear to be documented, although it has been available since MongoDB 2.2. I raised [DOCS-5246](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse) in the MongoDB issue tracker to follow up.